# How to use Map<Object, Double> in Endpoints Framework with Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization, gson, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a class `GChemin` which contains a `Map<GR2, Double>` attribute. GR2 contains four `double` attributes. When generating the client-libs, the map become an `JsonMap`.  My question is how to deal with this ?

I tried to populate the JsonMap with Gson formated JSON GR2 as key, but Endpoints can't handle it. I got this error :

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class GR2]`

**GR2 class** :

```
public class GR2 implements Serializable
    {

    public GR2(double x, double y)
        {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        }

    public GR2()
        {
        }

    @Override
    public String toString()
        {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("GR2 [x=");
        builder.append(this.x);
        builder.append(", y=");
        builder.append(this.y);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
        }


    public double getX()
        {
        return this.x;
        }

    public double getY()
        {
        return this.y;
        }

    public void setX(double x)
        {
        this.x = x;
        }

    public void setY(double y)
        {
        this.y = y;
        }

    private double x;
    private double y;
    }
```

**Converting Map to JsonMap** ( `toG()` method simply create a `GR2` object (serializable) from a `R2`) :

```
public static JsonMap toJsonMap(Map<R2, Double> map)
    {
    JsonMap jsonMap = new JsonMap();
    map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> jsonMap.put(toJSON(
                           toG(entry.getKey())), 
                           entry.getValue()));
    return jsonMap;
    }
```

**`toJson()` method** :

```
public static String toJSON(GR2 gr2)
    {
    return new Gson().toJson(gr2);
    }
```

**Api method** (gChemin contains the attribute `map`)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "save", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public GBoolean save(GChemin gChemin)
    {
    // Work with gChemin
    }
```

Comment: How are you expecting your object to be serialized?

Comment: @saiyr yes I do! But the serialization is done by Endpoints framework, usually I don't have any issues with it. It can serialize a List<GChemin> without problems.

Comment: I mean can you show an example JSON of what you expect?

Comment: @saiyr actually I don't expect any specific format of Json, I just want my object (with Map) to be transferred to the endpoint. But I must populate the JsonMap manually, right?
And I don't really know how to do it, but endpoints framework expects something specific.
If it's not possible to guess the right format, what would be a good work around?

Comment: This [pull](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/pull/137) fixes path parameter deserialization when the parameter is
an array-like structure. Reached it from [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/72876162). Would you think it's the same issue but now for Map structures?